# How does __test__ = False magic attribute work for test discovery

Tags: python

So I'm attempting to implement something similar to how unittesting frameworks do the following thing:

```
class BaseTest(T.TestCase):
    # Disables this test from being run
    __test__ = False

    def test_foo(self): pass


# However this test is picked up because it doesn't directly have __test__ set
class InheritingTest(BaseTest): pass
```

A thing I find peculiar:

```
# >> InheritingTest.__test__
# False
```

Which would indicate to me that it isn't using a [metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python) to set  `__test__` to `True` on construction of the type.

I tried grepping through the python library `find  . -name "*.py" | xargs grep '__test__'` but did not seem to find anything related to this.

My "guess" approach at solving this problem is to do the following:

```
def is_class_tested(cls):
    return cls.__dict__.get('__test__', True)
```

However this feels fragile to me... Is there a cleaner / nicer way to do this that works in all cases?  Is there ever a chance that a class will not have a `__dict__` property?

Comment: Why do you find it perculiar that InheritingTest.__test__ is False? The name resolution for this variable will be first to check the dict of InheritingTest and then to check the dict of BaseTest, where it finds it.

Comment: I find it peculiar because that test is run, despite it having `__test__ = False`

Comment: Can you post the code that decides whether or not a test should run?

Comment: What framework is this? The Python 2 `unittest` documentation doesn't mention this attribute; I'd never heard of it before.

Comment: Are you using doctest or nose?

Comment: I'm using a noselike test framework called https://github.com/Yelp/Testify

Comment: They do something similar to what I've posted above -- I wonder why my grep didn't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testify, the library you are using, does the following in `testify/test_discovery.py` around line 140:

```
    # it's not a list, it's not a bare module - let's see if it's an honest-to-god TestCaseBase
    elif isinstance(test_module, MetaTestCase) and (not '__test__' in test_module.__dict__ or bool(test_module.__test__)):
        ...
    # detect unittest test cases
    elif issubclass(test_module, unittest.TestCase) and (not '__test__' in test_module.__dict__ or bool(test_module.__test__)):
```

So, in other words, it is doing exactly what your "guess" approach does, in a slightly more verbose way: it tests for the presence and value of `__test__` in the class `__dict__` directly.

Answer (score -1):

**Is there ever a chance that a class will not have a __dict__ property?** My initial reaction to that is no.  That might not be *exactly* what you were asking because you *can* have an instance of a class without a `__dict__` if it defines `__slots__` and does not inherit from a class with a `__dict__` already in it.  See the `__slots__` description in the [Python Data Model description](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html)

**EDIT**:

> as pointed out by @nneonneo, comments below about the double underscore are not correct becuase there are trailing underscores.  The content is left in for historical reasons.

The behavior you claim looks peculiar, I think looks natural.  @Owen was right in asking about the code that that expects something different and thankyou for posting the reference to  [Yelp/Testify](https://github.com/Yelp/Testify).  That framework makes extensive use of the double_underscore.

Alex Martelli's [SO answer on the double_underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name-in-python) helps shed light on what might be going on but the very shortest answer is that the double underscore is returning the results above because the dot notation of `InheritingTest.__test__` goes through the normal attribute resolution machinery but the Testify framework, by deciding to use the leading double_underscore, has reserved the right to access it at it's class scope even if your subclass overrides it.

Test frameworks are, by their very nature, magical beasts and the use of `__test__` hear looks proper on their part.  I checked out their docs and the documentation feels sparse so *your* using `__test__` at all feels dangerous (the double underscore kind of signals *hands off* this "class local" variable anyway).

Comment: `__test__` has *two trailing underscores*, exempting it from the usual name mangling. It is *not* a 'class-local attribute'.

Comment: Unless I'm very much mistaken, a class with `__slots__` does not have to have a `__dict__`.

Comment: @Marcin more like usually does not have a `__dict__`.  The question appeared to be concerned with the *class* level `__dict__` as opposed the the instance level.  `__slots__` means that there is not `__dict__` on the *instnace*.  Also, `__slots__` does not guarantee that there is no `__dict__` at the instance level because if one is there from a parent class then there will be both `__slots__` and `__dict__`.