# cannot collect test class 'TestMain' because it has a __init__ constructor (from: Login.py)

Tags: automation, pycharm, pytest

I am trying to run pytest from cmd and I'm getting this result when I execute **pytest Login.py**:

```
================================================== warnings summary ===================================================
C:\automation\test\test.py:36
  C:\automation\test\test.py:36: PytestCollectionWarning: cannot collect test class 'TestMain' because it has a __init__ constructor (from: Login.py)
    class TestBase():

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html
================================================= 1 warning in 59.69s =================================================
```

Inside Login.py, I have an import and I think that might be the problem, but I need that import for the test. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like you need to remove the "__init__" method from the "TestMain" class. Can't say more without more details.

Answer (score 34):

If your not-test class starts with the word `Test`, you can also define `__test__ = False` in the class body to prevent pytest from trying to discover tests in the class, for example:

```py
class TestNotATestCase:
    __test__ = False
```

Also see [How does __test__ = False magic attribute work for test discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434855/how-does-test-false-magic-attribute-work-for-test-discovery).

Answer (score 12):

#### Collecting Tests

"Collecting tests" in pytest-speak means discovering/deciding which functions to run as test cases.  PyTest discovers tests according to a small [set of rules](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/explanation/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery) including the following:

> test prefixed test functions or methods inside Test prefixed test classes (without an `__init__` method)

#### The Warning

This `PytestCollectionWarning` is pointing out that the member methods of `TestMain` won't be treated as test cases since the class has an `__init__` method.  It's a warning because you might really want those to be used as test cases but mistakenly added an `__init__` method.  However, it may be that you just have a class that starts with the word `Test` and so the warning is a false alarm.

#### Solutions

The solution depends on what you are aiming for:

- If `TestMain` *is* meant to be a collection of tests then you should remove the `__init__` method as @fstamour suggested (or look for an alternative as @EscBlack is suggesting).
- If `TestMain` *is not* a collection of tests *but* you do want/need its name to start with "Test", then there are ways to [filter the warning explicitly](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#module-warnings).
- If `TestMain` is not a collection of tests *and* you really don't need its name to start with "Test" anyway, then just rename it.  **This was the solution for me** when I had made a dummy class called `TestData` to use inside some test cases. Changing the name to `MyData` got rid of the warning.  (Since you are running `pytest Login.py`, I'm guessing that `Login.py` contains both implementation and tests which makes it all the more likely to have non-test classes with names that start with "Test".)

Comment: Classes starting with the word Test were my issue. Thanks!

Comment: For bullet one, how do you define members in that case? As you get a pylint warning when defining it in `setup_class()`

Comment: Okay, simple, define them outside __init__ (without self. prefix)

Answer (score 8):

you can use `setup_class` insetead of `__init__`.

https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/xunit_setup.html?highlight=setup