# Test cases for two functions with different implementations but return same value

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have two functions with different implementations that return the same value, how do I run the same set of test cases for both the functions without violating the DRY principle?
for example: I'm implementing recursive and imperative way of implementing factorial of number. I want same set of test cases to run for both the functions. How can I implement without violating DRY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two implementations share a *contract* that you can express through a set of tests. For example, imagine two functions that double their input:

```
def double_by_multiplying(value):
    return 2 * value


def double_by_adding(value):
    return value + value
```

Using one of the methods suggested in [abstract test case using python unittest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4566910/3001761), we can write a general set of tests for any function that doubles its input, then create subclasses that use each of our two implementations:

```
from unittest import TestCase


class DoublingContract:

    def test_input_gets_doubled(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.implementation(1), 2)


class DoubleMultiplicationTests(DoublingContract, TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.implementation = double_by_multiplying


class DoubleAdditionTests(DoublingContract, TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.implementation = double_by_adding
```