# How should a Python (unittest) superclass method reference a variable in its calling subclass?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am simply not experienced enough in Python OO programming to know how this is done: If I have several classes that are subclasses of a `unittest.TestCase` subclass. How should the superclass' methods reference variables of the subclasses when the latter call these methods? Let me try to illustrate it with this, probably wrong, example:

```
import unittest

class TestSuper(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_method(self):
        # do something, e.g.
        pass

class TestSub1(TestSuper):

    def setUp(self):
        self.some_parameter = 1

class TestSub2(TestSuper):

    def setUp(self):
        self.some_parameter = 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Now, I cannot figure out how to correcty reference `TestSub1.parameter` or `TestSub2.parameter`, respectively, when `TestSuper.test_method` is called from the subclasses.

I am inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/25695512/865169, but here I am trying achieve having multiple test cases that do the same but only differ in their set-up. I can of course achieve all this by just copy-pasting my test case definitions, but I find that bad coding practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `self.some_parameter`; `self` is always bound to the right instance here.

However, take into account that `unittest.main()` will run `test_method` on *all three test cases (the baseclass included), so you'll have to provide a default value for `some_parameter` on the base class.

If you don't want `TestSuper` to be seen as a test case, don't inherit from `unittest.TestCase`. Use it as a mix-in instead:

```
import unittest

class TestMixin(object):
    def test_method(self):
        # do something, e.g.
        pass

class TestSub1(unittest.TestCase, TestMixin):
    def setUp(self):
        self.some_parameter = 1

class TestSub2(unittest.TestCase, TestMixin):
    def setUp(self):
        self.some_parameter = 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Now `unittest.main()` will only find *two* test cases (`TestSub1` and `TestSub2`) and run `test_method` only on those cases.

Comment: Well, I was a bit scared of the mixin approach due to http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201210/multiple_inheritance_is_hard.html

Comment: @vadim-p suggests hiding the baseclass inside a non-TestCase class in order to skip the test in the baseclass: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25695512/865169

Comment: @ThomasArildsen: you are not providing the same methods in a base and a mixin. Proper use of mixins is not that hard though. Also see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo for a great explanation of what goes on with multiple inheritance.

Comment: @ThomasArildsen: the hiding 'hack' is that, a hack, and is not needed. It causes confusion and reduces readability.

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand this. In my somewhat more complicated real test, the hiding hack works, but the mixin does not. In the latter case, the error messages seem to indicate that Python expects self to refer to TestMixin, so it cannot find the parameter that is in TestSub1, for example.

Comment: @ThomasArildsen: then your mixin is (indirectly?) still inheriting from `TestCase`; it is being run.

Comment: Oh, right. The mixin needs to inherit `assert`-functions from `unittest` which are usually run as `self.assert`... in tests. How to do that then?

Comment: @ThomasArildsen: it doesn't have to inherit those. The `assert*` methods will be available via the subclasses.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101391/discussion-between-thomas-arildsen-and-martijn-pieters).