# unittest discover - Inherited test methods being executed twice

Tags: python, python-unittest

**Situation 1**

Suppose I have a test class that I'd like to re-use, `test_doubled.py`:

```
import unittest

class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

It contains a singled class, `BaseTestCase`, that inherits from `unittest.TestCase` and has a single test method.

Running the test from the command line produces the following output as expected:

```
$ python -m unittest discover -p test_doubled.py -v
test_something (test_doubled.BaseTestCase) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

**Situation 2**

Now suppose I add a second module, `test_doubled_2.py`, like so:

```
from test_doubled import BaseTestCase

class DerivedTestCase(BaseTestCase):
    pass
```

It inherits from `BaseTestCase`, so I expect that it will have the same test method, and that the test method will get executed. However, when I run it, I get the following output:

```
$ python -m unittest discover -p test_doubled_2.py -v
test_something (test_doubled.BaseTestCase) ... ok
test_something (test_doubled_2.DerivedTestCase) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

It seems to run the method twice, once for the derived class, and once for the base class. This is not what I expect at all.

**Situation 3**

My suspicion is that, by importing `BaseTestCase` from `test_doubled_2.py`, the whole `BaseTestCase` class is getting executed. This seems to be confirmed by running both test modules:

```
$ python -m unittest discover -p test_doubled\*.py -v
test_something (test_doubled.BaseTestCase) ... ok
test_something (test_doubled.BaseTestCase) ... ok
test_something (test_doubled_2.DerivedTestCase) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Running both modules executes the same test method *three times*, when I would expect it to be executed only twice.

**How can I get the test method to only execute once in Situation 2 and twice in Situation 3?**

---

**UPDATE**

To clarify, the `BaseTestCase` should be a usable test on its own, so making it a mixin won't work. I only want to prevent it from getting executed extra times.

Here is the desired outcome:

1. Running just the `BaseTestCase` test in `test_doubled.py`:

   ```
   $ python -m unittest discover -p test_doubled.py -v
   test_something (test_doubled.BaseTestCase) ... ok

   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   Ran 1 test in 0.000s

   OK
   ```

   This already works as desired.
2. Running just the `DerivedTestCase` in `test_doubled_2.py`:

   ```
   $ python -m unittest discover -p test_doubled_2.py -v
   test_something (test_doubled_2.DerivedTestCase) ... ok

   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

   OK
   ```

   It should only execute the `DerivedTestCase`, and *not* the `BaseTestCase`.
3. Running both:

   ```
   $ python -m unittest discover -p test_doubled\*.py -v
   test_something (test_doubled.BaseTestCase) ... ok
   test_something (test_doubled_2.DerivedTestCase) ... ok

   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   Ran 3 tests in 0.000s

   OK
   ```

   The test method is executed exactly twice, once for `BaseTestcase` and once for `DerivedTestCase`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323455/python-unit-test-with-base-and-sub-class, second answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python unit test with base and sub class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323455/python-unit-test-with-base-and-sub-class)

Comment: @Wyatt That's not quite what I'm asking. I still want the base test class to be usable in its own right. I have updated the question to clarify.

Comment: You could make `BaseTestCase` inherit the mixin as well. I edited my answer to reflect this but deleted it because the other answer discusses this option and some others plus the trade-offs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a mixin like this:

```
# mixin.py
class TestMixin(object):

    def test_something(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)


# test_base.py
import unittest
from .mixin import TestMixin

class BaseTestCase(TestMixin, unittest.TestCase):

    pass


# test_derived.py
import unittest
from .mixin import TestMixin

class DerivedTestCase(TestMixin, unittest.TestCase):

    pass
```

Comment: Ah, yes. I see now. That does achieve the desired result. I had hoped to avoid creating more classes, but it looks like it's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use multiple inheritance it will bite you later.

Use a wrapping approach as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/25695512/328384