# Use different implementations of `setUp` and `tearDown` of unittest.TestCase instances

Tags: python, inheritance, mixins, python-unittest

I want to run a set of tests under different conditions and therefore share these tests between two different `TestCase`-derived classes.
One creates its own standalone session and the other attaches to an existing session and executes the same tests in there.

I guess I'm kind of abusing the `unittest` framework when testing an API with it but it doesn't feel like it's too far from its original purpose. Am I good so far?

I hacked a few things together and got it kind of running. But the way it's done, doesn't feel right and I'm afraid will cause problems sooner or later.

These are the problems I have with my solution:

- When simply running the thing with PyCharm without limiting the tests, it attempts to run not only the intended `StandaloneSessionTests` and `ExistingSessionTests` but also `GroupOfTests` which is only the collection and has no session, i.e. execution context.
- I can make it *not* run `GroupOfTests` by not deriving that one from `TestCase` but then PyCharm complains that it doesn't know about the `assert...()` functions. Rightly so, because `GroupOfTest` only gets indirect access to these functions at runtime when a derived class also inherits from `TestCase`. Coming from a C++ background, this feels like black magic and I don't think I should be doing this.

I tried passing the session creation classes to the constructor of `GroupOfTests` like this: `__init__(self, session_class)`. But this causes problems when the `unittest` framework attempts to instantiate the tests: It doesn't know what to do with the additional `__init__` parameter.

I learned about `@classmethod`, which seems to be a way to get around the "only one constructor" limitation of Python but I couldn't figure out a way to get it running.

I'm looking for a solution that lets me state something as straightforward as this:

```
suite = unittest.TestSuite()
suite.addTest(GroupOfTests(UseExistingSession))
suite.addTest(GroupOfTests(CreateStandaloneSession))
...
```

This is what I got so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import unittest


def existing_session():
    return "existingsession"


def create_session():
    return "123"


def close_session(session_id):
    print("close session %s" % session_id)
    return True


def do_thing(session_id):
    return len(session_id)


class GroupOfTests(unittest.TestCase):  # GroupOfTests gets executed, which makes no sense.
#class GroupOfTests:  # use of assertGreaterThan() causes pycharm warning
    session_id = None

    def test_stuff(self):
        the_thing = do_thing(self.session_id)
        self.assertGreater(the_thing, 2)

    # Original code contains many other tests, which must not be duplicated


class UseExistingSession(unittest.TestCase):
    session_id = None

    def setUp(self):
        self.session_id = existing_session()

    def tearDown(self):
        pass  # Nothing to do


class CreateStandaloneSession(unittest.TestCase):
    session_id = None

    def setUp(self):
        self.session_id = create_session()

    def tearDown(self):
        close_session(self.session_id)


# unittest framework runs inherited test_stuff()
class StandaloneSessionTests(CreateStandaloneSession, GroupOfTests):
    pass


# unittest framework runs inherited test_stuff()
class ExistingSessionTests(UseExistingSession, GroupOfTests):
    pass


def main():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(StandaloneSessionTests)
    suite.addTest(ExistingSessionTests)

    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    runner.run(suite())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323455/python-unit-test-with-base-and-sub-class) is the best solution I think. I believe that is one of the things you describe, but where pycharm said these methods don't exist. Ignore that or add these functions to the class with `raise NotImplementetError`, which will let pycharm believe this is a abstract class.

Comment: @MegaIng Sorry for the delay, I've been rather busy: I followed your advice and silenced PyCharm by defining the assert functions of `TestCase` that' I'm using. If you created an answer from your comment I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: I answered you can now accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if using [`pytest`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/index.html) is an option for you but if so, here is an example which might do what you want.

```
import pytest


class Session:
    def __init__(self, session_id=None):
        self.id = session_id


existing_session = Session(999)
new_session = Session(111)


@pytest.fixture(params=[existing_session, new_session])
def session_fixture(request):
    return request.param


class TestGroup:
    def test_stuff(self, session_fixture):
        print('(1) Test with session: {}'.format(session_fixture.id))
        assert True

    def test_more_stuff(self, session_fixture):
        print('(2) Test with session: {}'.format(session_fixture.id))
        assert True
```

Output:

```
$ pytest -v -s hmm.py
======================================================= test session starts ========================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.4.1, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0 -- /home/lettuce/Dropbox/Python/Python_3/venv/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/lettuce/Dropbox/Python/Python_3, inifile:
collected 4 items                                                                                                                  

hmm.py::TestGroup::test_stuff[session_fixture0] (1) Test with session: 999
PASSED
hmm.py::TestGroup::test_stuff[session_fixture1] (1) Test with session: 111
PASSED
hmm.py::TestGroup::test_more_stuff[session_fixture0] (2) Test with session: 999
PASSED
hmm.py::TestGroup::test_more_stuff[session_fixture1] (2) Test with session: 111
PASSED

===================================================== 4 passed in 0.01 seconds =====================================================
```

If you are actually going to use `pytest` you will probably want follow the [conventions for Python test discovery](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery) rather than using `hmm.py` as a filename though!

Comment: Just to let you know, while my problem got initially solved by @MegaIng's answer, I later needed further combinations and doing this with inheritance just wasn't feasible anymore. I now am using pytest with parametrized fixtures as you suggested.

Comment: @foraidt Glad to hear, there are many benefits to using pytest. Seems like this should be the accepted answer then.

Comment: You're right, I didn't think it was possible to change the accepted answer; thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

You can get pycharm to ignore these not existing function by creating abstract methods with `raise NotImplementetError`:

```
class GroupOfTests:
    session_id = None

    def test_stuff(self):
        the_thing = do_thing(self.session_id)
        self.assertGreater(the_thing, 2)

    def assertGreater(self, a, b): # Pycharm treats these like abstract methods from the ABC module
        raise NotImplementetError
```

This will let python believe this is an abstract class and will make pycharm raise errors if a subclass doesn't define these functions.