# Python unittest skip test for only one subclass

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-decorators

Let's say I have my unittest set up like this:

```
import unittest

class BaseTest(object):
    def setup(self):
        self.foo = None

    def test_something(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.foo.something())

    def test_another(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.foo.another())

    def test_a_third_thing(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.foo.a_third_thing())

class TestA(BaseTest, unittest.TestCase):
    def setup(self):
        self.foo = FooA()


class TestB(BaseTest, unittest.TestCase):
    def setup(self):
        self.foo = FooB()


class TestC(BaseTest, unittest.TestCase):
    def setup(self):
        self.foo = FooC()
```

Now let's say `FooC` doesn't have `a_third_thing` implemented yet, and I want to skip `test_a_third_thing` for ONLY the `TestC` class. Is there some way I can use the `@unittest.skipif` decorator to do this? Or some other handy way to skip this test for only this class?

Python 2.7, in case it matters

Comment: BaseTest should inherit TestCase

Comment: You could override the test in `TestC`, e.g. `def test_a_third_thing(self): pass`

Comment: @pylang This is what I ended up doing, want to add it as an answer?

Comment: Done.  If you do find a way to skip tests, I'm curious to see what you find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not need to "skip" the test.  One simple approach is to override the base test with a dummy.

```
class TestC(BaseTest, unittest.TestCase):
    def setup(self):
        self.foo = FooC()

    def test_a_third_thing(self):
        """Override the assertions of the base test."""
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `@unittest.skipif` here because it is evaluated during module, and the check needed should be run during runtime.

To achieve desired result your `test_a_third_thing` in base class should look like this:

```
class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):   
    def test_a_third_thing(self):
        if not getattr(self.foo, "a_third_thing", None):
            self.skipTest(self.foo.__class__.__name__ + ' has no a_third_thing, skip')
        else:
            self.assertTrue(self.foo.a_third_thing())
```

Also fix typos in your example `setup` to `setUp`. Remove 'unittest.TestCase' from inheritance list of test classes and add to base class.

Comment: Thank you. There are no typos in my example, BaseTest deliberately does not inherit from TestCase, because I do not want to run tests for the BaseTest (it has no valid foo attribute). See this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323455/python-unit-test-with-base-and-sub-class

Comment: @C_Z_ if this answered your question can you accept this answer?

Comment: this does not answer my questions specifically, for instance let's say I do have a `foo` method defined for FooC but it is not completely implemented, and is returning 'False' instead. Possibly overwriting the test in TestC, as pylang suggested, is the way to go.